# What is a word equivalent to 'oceanic' but specific to a lake?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, analogy, geography

What is a word equivalent to 'oceanic' but specific to a lake?

It'd be the blank in this analogy:

*oceanic : ocean :: _____ : lake*
(*oceanic is to ocean as _____ is to lake*)

The context in which I'm trying to use this word is something like what follows:

> Oceanic creatures, as opposed to _____ creatures...

(I'm trying to avoid using 'creatures that live in lakes' for the second part)

The obvious construction that comes to my mind is 'lakely,' but given that this is not in the dictionary, I'd appreciate an actual word.

Comment: @LucianSava: Better would be *freshwater creatures*. ;-)

Comment: Given that limnologists study lakes, do you mean like how limnology is the freshwater equivalent of oceanography? Or are you looking for something to oppose pelagic creatures and estuarine creatures?

Comment: the former; a word that substantiates the distinction of something being 'from/of a lake.'

Comment: @LucianSava "freshwater" includes rivers and streams as well as lakes, which may or may not be what is wanted.

Comment: My silly brain went with "Laconic", which means something like "Terse" or "Minimal" in speech. Wrong meaning entirely, but I bet there's a pun somewhere in there.

Comment: Also, usually you would say "marine" instead of "oceanic". I believe oceanic actually refers to the specific area of islands called Oceana.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 - now I know why my ears were burning.

Comment: Somehow, I think playing Ringo Starr's Octopus' Garden would be appropriate.

Comment: Do you actually mean "oceanic" creatures or all marine (salt water) life? Oceanic specifically means pertaining to oceans and so excludes seas and other biomes with high salinity. It sounds like the distinction you are after is between "marine" (salt water) and "freshwater" aquatic creatures.

Comment: If you want this to work for a non-scientific audience, I think you should stick to "salt water" and "fresh water"  if you want to group rivers and lakes together or "salt water" and "lake dwelling" if you want to exclude animals that live in rivers from either group.  This will get the point across far better.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

One possibility is **lacustrine**,

which Merriam-Webster defines as:

> of, relating to, formed in, living in, or growing in lakes

Another possibility, and the one I'd recommend if you're not writing for a scientific audience (and maybe even if you are), is
just to say *as opposed to lake creatures*, using *lake* as an attributive noun.

Comment: I'd take it a step further: *ocean creatures, as opposed to lake creatures...*

Comment: Lacustrine works perfectly, thank you :)

Comment: Nah, it's a cool word I say use it :)

Comment: I'm got a doctorate in biology, and I didn't know this word. I would avoid it.

Comment: @JackAidley Your doctorate is irrelevant to the question and to the answer. The answer proposes a term that is well-known in limnological work.

Comment: Appropriateness depends on the audience, but it wouldn't be the first time someone had to look up a word.

Comment: @Anton: I'm sure the word has a place. However, if the OP is asking then it is likely that they are not, in fact, part of a community in which the word is widely used or understood. An obscure technical term that even an audience with relevant education doesn't understand is unlikely to be the best choice of word.

Comment: @JackAidley Google ngrams indicate that this word hit its prime in the 1830s, so I'm not surprised you haven't come across it in biology study. It's a cool word, but I don't know how many people will understand it immediately.

Comment: French speaking persons will understand it well because ``lacustre`` was the first thing that came to me, and according to google n-gram it reached its peak in 1974.

Comment: Context matters.  If designing an item for a "Miller Analogies Test," a word almost no one knows would be inappropriate.  Because then you'd be testing for knowledge of obscure vocabulary instead of analogy skill.

Comment: Sometimes people enjoy coming across a word they have not seen before then looking it up in the dictionary.  I know I do.

Comment: The OED definition supports that this may be a suitable word after all: "Of or pertaining to a lake or lakes. *Said esp. of plants and animals inhabiting lakes*, and Geology of strata, etc., which originated by deposition at the bottom of lakes" (my emphasis). Feel free to add this information to this answer if you think it's useful.

Comment: 'lacustre' is also a word Spanish, with meaning "of or related to lakes".

Comment: >26 million (raw) Google hits supports my feeling that 'lacustrine' is far from obscure.

Answer (score 52):

Since virtually nobody is going to know Peter Shor's erudite offering (*lacustrine*), you might try a simpler equivalent: **lake-dwelling**.

The equivalence would then be *oceanic creatures* vs. *lake-dwelling creatures*.

Comment: [Lacustrine vs lake-dwelling](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lacustrine%2Clake-dwelling&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) on Google Ngram

Comment: @sourcream: That matters not at all. The point is, if you addressed 100% of the English-speaking population, virtually everyone would understand "lake-dwelling" while only a very tiny fraction (did you look at the values in the y-axis of the graph?) would understand "lacustrine." Besides, NGrams are virtually worthless for drawing conclusions about language.

Comment: See [this post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu) on the Meta version of this stack.

Comment: "virtually nobody", "matters not at all", "virtually everyone", "virtually worthless". All I see are bold claims without any evidence.

Comment: Some things should be self-evident.

Comment: @sourcream are you genuinely demanding citations for a claim that "lacustrine" is going to be understood by far fewer people than "lake-dwelling"?

Comment: @sourcream I've never heard the word "lacustrine" before, and that _is_ strong evidence that it's an obscure word. Both the word "lake" and the word "dwelling" seem like common words to me, and that's evidence that most English speakers know what both of those words mean.

Comment: Saying that "lake-dwelling" will be more widely recognized than "lacustrine" is not a bold claim, it's self-evident from the fact that "Lake-dwelling" is a compound word made of two much more common words. The fact that the combination of the two is rare in literature does not mean the individual words themselves are poorly understood, nor does it change the way people read compound words. Google Ngrams is NOT a measure of how widely understood a word will be.

Comment: And really I think "lake" is sufficient. "Lake boats". "Lake fish". I think the problem is that rarely is anything specific to a "lake" setting. If it can live in a lake, it can probably live in a river or a pond, so "freshwater" is the better term anyway. (Although lake boat is a real term because they tend to be shallow and flat bottomed so unsuitable for much other than an actual lake.)

Comment: Although so-called "lake boats" are quite inappropriate for larger lakes, e.g. any of the Great Lakes. :)

Comment: A better NGram with more context:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lacustrine%2Clake-dwelling%2Clake%2Cdwelling&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Comment: Lacustrine is quite a common geologic term, so it's not really as obscure as you make it seem.

Comment: @spacetyper So is *plagioclase*, but it's doubtful many lay people would understand it.

Answer (score 29):

**Limnic** is a term that can be considered which covers other still freshwater bodies like swamps and ponds also, but not flowing bodies of water like rivers. It was borrowed from German *limnisch*, and it is ultimately from Greek *λίμνη* (límnē) 'lake, marsh, basin'.

The definition of the adjective *limnic* from two dictionaries:

> relating to bodies of water with low salt concentration, such as lakes and ponds
>
> *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/limnic)*

> 1. Relating to fresh water, typically a lake or swamp; freshwater
> 2. *(geology)* deposited in a lake or swamp
>
> *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/limnic)*

It appears to be mainly used in geology and a more familiar usage is in the term *limnic eruption* (a natural disaster in which dissolved carbon dioxide suddenly erupts from deep lake waters). I've also found usages where the adjective *limnic* modifies *fauna* (the animals of a particular region or time period). Example usage:

> The terrestrial fauna of the world’s largest mountain range, the Himalayas, has been moderately well studied, but this is not the case with the limnic fauna, and especially molluscs.
>
> <sub><sup>Ulrich Bößneck, Catharina Clewing, and Christian Albrecht "Exploring high-mountain limnic faunas: discovery of a novel endemic bivalve species (Sphaeriidae : Pisidium) in the Nepal Himalayas," Invertebrate Systematics 30(6), 588-597, (13 December 2016). https://doi.org/10.1071/IS15043</sup></sub>

Answer (score 12):

Lentic:

> : of, relating to, or living in still waters (such as lakes, ponds, or swamps)
>
> *[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lentic)*

Comment: Also spelled *lenitic*. You should tell people this stillwater word of yours comes from Latin *lentus* for slow. Here’s its swiftwater antonym *lotic* (<L. *lotus*) in action: “Along the shores of the Great Lakes there are lotic communities where the wave action is incessant, thus producing the fundamental conditions of a lotic environment and presenting an exception to the general statement that all lotic environments are streams.” ―R. N. Chapman in his *Animal Ecology* xvii. 347 from 1937.

Comment: Presumably this is a sibling term to Benthic

Answer (score 7):

I come late to this discussion but, being an oceanographer (and to a lesser  extent a limnologist), I am well used to the adjective *oceanographic* and noun *oceanography*, with the corresponding freshwater equivalents *limnological* and *limnology*.

With that in mind, *oceanic* refers to oceans, bodies of marine water (typical salt content 3.5%), whereas *limnic* refers to bodies of relatively low or zero salt content.

A reliable non-technical definition of limnic is given by Collins:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/limnic)
> limnic:
> relating to bodies of water with low salt concentration, such as lakes and ponds

The adjective *limnic* therefore applies to rivers, lakes, streams and other volumes of fresh or near fresh water and is not a word confined to lakes.

Hence, *limnic* and its associated words (*limnology*, *limnological*) include lakes but are not restricted to them.

Two alternatives remain: *limnetic* and *lacustrine*

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/limnetic)
> limnetic:
> of, relating to, or inhabiting the open water of a body of fresh water

Merriam Webster exemplifies the commonly understood definition of *lacustrine*:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lacustrine)
> lacustrine:
> of, relating to, formed in, living in, or growing in lakes

There is a comprehensive literature that uses the word. See for numerous examples too many to quote here:

https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=studies+of+a+lacustrine+thermocline&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart

Of these two possibilities, the prime candidate specific to lakes is thus **lacustrine**

And that is why I voted for the relevant earlier answer.

Comment: I've already explained what _limnic_ is with all the details and mentioned as a term that can be considered. _Lacustrine_ was already accepted as the answer and people can give alternative answers. I'm not just giving a word with no details and thoughts. For example, you've mentioned _limnological_, and it means  "of or pertaining to limnology" and it is mainly used as "limnological studies". Perhaps, you could write a comment about your thoughts (without the repetitions).

Comment: @ermanen I think it entirely clear that you answered with details and thought; that and your assiduity are not in question.  Equally, I hope I made clear that limnic, limnological and limnology all deal with water of salinity low relative to the sea. This group of words is therefore not specific to lakes. The more restricted word, only applicable to lakes, is lacustrine. As I remarked, I came late to this, recognise the effort others have made, so wrote no more than is necessary to clarify the point.

Answer (score 1):

Limnal.
Not to be confused with liminal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: _Limnic_ is the preferred word from the same root which I've provided [in my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/598755/64985). Only _MW_ defines _limnal_ as "of or relating to lakes" with no citations and the word is not in _OED_. _Limnal_ is an unfortunate coinage as there is _liminal_ also and google search tries to correct it to _liminal_. It is not really used, even in scientific context.